# Failure to find org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin-jar

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am new to Maven and while importing an existing Maven project from the pom.xml I find that the  following error occurs.

**Failure to find org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin-jar:1.4.4**.Should I remove any Dependency to fix this?

[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1wCF.png)
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use images better past text into the post...

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.I won't use it from next time.

Answer (score 2):

It was solved by adding the dependency in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Including configuration :

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>MainClassName</mainClass>
                        <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                        <filename>
                            ${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}
                        </filename>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It works like charm.